# Error while calling a Javascript function on HTML link click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textbox, ip-address

I have a text box, an HTML link & a JavaScript function.

JavaScript function is used to get client machine's IP-address. When I click on the link, I am trying to call this function & display the result in my textbox. However, I fail to obtain the result.

This is the error I am getting.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ip' of undefined
```

My text box:

```
<input type="text" id="txtmyip" name="txtmyip"readonly>
```

My HTML link:

```
<a href="#" onclick="DisplayIP();" >Show IP Address</a>
```

My Javascript function:

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
            script.type = "text/javascript";
            script.src = "http://www.telize.com/jsonip?callback=DisplayIP";
            document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);

            function DisplayIP(response)
            {
                document.getElementById("txtmyip").value = response.ip;
            }
```

Comment: actually `response` is also `undefined`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to separate JSONP request function and display function. For example:

```
function displayIP() {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = "http://www.telize.com/jsonip?callback=populateIP";
    document.head.appendChild(script);    
}

function populateIP(response) {
    document.getElementById("txtmyip").value = response.ip;
}
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Gr632/

Answer (score 3):

The function `DisplayIP` expects a single parameter, `response`, but when it's called with `onclick="DisplayIP()"` no value is passed in for that parameter.  So it's now trying to read `response.ip` for an undefined `response`.